# MATLAB codegen: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version: 'GLIBCXX_3.4_20' not found

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

Trying to run codegen with MATLAB 2019a on a linux box and got the error:

```
... /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version: 'GLIBCXX_3.4_20' not found ...
```

I have /lib64/libstdc++.so.6, just (apparently) not the right version. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/support/sysreq/files/system-requirements-release-2019a-supported-compilers.pdf) is a list of supported compilers for your version of MATLAB.

Apparently MATLAB R2019a on Linux requires GCC 6.3.x. Make sure you have that version installed.